# How to determine and validate the resolution of the video?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, video, multipartform-data, media

Receiving video file from multipart/form on request as IFromFile.

```cs
public class UploadMediaRequest
{
    [Required]
    public IFormFile Media { get; set; }
}
```

How could I validate the resolution of this video? For example resolution of the video should be 800px x 468px, and if received 1920px x 1080px return an error.

Using:
**.NET 7
ASP.NET Core 7**

Comment: Use `ffprobe.exe`

Comment: As Dai says, you need to save the file somewhere, then run ffprobe over it.

Comment: did you try Vlc.DotNet https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet

Comment: Looking at Nuget.org, you could try using FFMpegCore https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFMpegCore or NReco.VideoInfo https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.VideoInfo

Comment: @Ghassen That library hasn't been updated for 3 years, was archived in early 2022 and is only for WinForms

Comment: @LoLo2207 Both of those libraries are just wrappers for ffprobe.

Comment: @DavidG Is actually there any way to not create and save file?

Comment: @kanils_ Video files can be _gigabyte_-sized or larger - just save it to `%TEMP%`.

Comment: @Dai Well yes, however my size of the service in kuber is limited. So this is no really good approach. To save all files from user, even if they are `TEMP` .

Comment: "return an error."  Where do you want to show the error ? Before submit form or  ?

Comment: @QingGuo when request is made, I want to validate whether resolution is expected and return 400 for example.

Answer (score 2):

We can use an event listener on the change event of the input. When the user selects a file the event listener callback grabs the file (using event.target.files[0]), creates a new video element, and sets the src of the video element to a DOMString containing a URL representing the file object.

The `onloadedmetadata` event is fired when the [metadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#media) has been loaded - all attributes now contain the information we need. Within the callback for this event we'll retrieve the videoHeight and videoWidth of the video element we created before. These values give the resolution of the video file.

The demo like below:

```
@model UploadMediaRequest
<form asp-action="CheckPost" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  
    <input asp-for="Media" id="video-upload" type="file" />
  
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>

 <script>
const fileUpload = document.getElementById("video-upload");
 
 fileUpload.addEventListener("change", event => {
     const resultEl = document.getElementById("meta");
     const file = event.target.files[0];
     const videoEl = document.createElement("video");
     videoEl.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    
     // When the video metadata has loaded, check
     // the video width/height
     videoEl.onloadedmetadata = event => {
         window.URL.revokeObjectURL(videoEl.src);
         const { name, type } = file;
         const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = videoEl;
         var resolution = `${videoWidth}px x ${videoHeight}px`;
         if (resolution != "800x x 468px") {
             alert("Error! The  resolution of the video should be 800px x 468px ");
             $("#video-upload").val('');

         }
     }
  })
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Okey it's cool solution. That also should be made on Front-end side. However the question related more to backend.